# Use associated type protocol as a return type of a generic function

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

Protocols with associated types is confusing:

```
// Lets say I have two possible type of responses
struct OtpResponse {}
struct SsoResponse {}

// A simple protocol to mandate the return of token from respective concrete type
protocol AuthenticationProvider {
    associatedtype ResponseType
    func getToken(completion: @escaping (ResponseType?, NSError?) -> Void)
}

// A type of auth provider
struct OtpBasedAuthProvider:AuthenticationProvider {
    typealias ResponseType = OtpResponse
    func getToken(completion: @escaping (OtpResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        let otpResponse = OtpResponse()
        completion(otpResponse, nil)
    }
}

// Another type of auth provider
struct SsoBasedAuthProvider: AuthenticationProvider {
    typealias ResponseType = SsoResponse
    func getToken(completion: @escaping (SsoResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        let ssoResponse = SsoResponse()
        completion(ssoResponse, nil)
    }
}

// There is some external logic to decide which type of auth provider to be used
func getProviderTypeFromSomeLogicOtherLogic() -> Int{
    return 1 // simply for dummy
}

// Factory to return a concrete implementaton of auth provider
class AuthProviderFactory {
    func getAuthProvider<T: AuthenticationProvider>(type:Int) -> T {
        if type == 1 {
            return SsoBasedAuthProvider() as! T
        }
        else {
            return OtpBasedAuthProvider() as! T
        }
    }
}
```

Now to use the code above, I want to do something like this:

```
func executeNetworkCall() -> Void {
    let factory = AuthProviderFactory() // 1
    let authProvider = factory.getAuthProvider(type:  getProviderTypeFromSomeLogicOtherLogic()) // 2
    authProvider.getToken{ (resp, error) in // 3
        // some code
    }
}
```

In the above, line number 2 where I am trying to get provider type from factory is giving me error as :

> **Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred**.

I know I can get rid of compilation error by doing something like this :

```
let authProvider:SsoBasedAuthProvider = factory.getAuthProvider(type: getProviderTypeFromSomeLogicOtherLogic())
```

But thats not the point, I dont know which provider will be returned and I want to call .getToken from that provider.

Comment: Well if you don't know which provider will be returned, what would be the type of `resp`? If you don't know its type, how will this design be any useful? Is there perhaps a set of common members among the two response types, that you know `resp` would definitely have?

Comment: I want to pass the response object to the caller of this API executeNetworkCall(), I would rather be more interested to check if error object is not nil, if not, whatever is in resp, just pass as it is

Comment: What does the caller accept? Does it accept `Any`? Can you show what you are going to with `resp`? What do you mean by "pass as it is"? To where?

Comment: ok, let me modify this in the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocols with `associatedtype` can’t be used in form of composition, which is a drawback and definitely irritating sometimes. But, you can create your own `Type Erasure` class to make this work.

You can study more about type erasure from this link: https://www.donnywals.com/understanding-type-erasure-in-swift/. You can find many more on Google.

This is how Apple has implemented it internally, by making few changes we can make it work our way.

Below is the code I came up with:

```
 //Let's say I have two possible type of responses
struct OtpResponse{}
struct SsoResponse{}

//A simple protocol to mandate the return of token from respective concrete type
protocol AuthenticationProvider{
    associatedtype ResponseType
    func getToken(completion: @escaping(ResponseType?, NSError?) -> Void)
}

//A type of auth provider
struct OtpBasedAuthProvider:AuthenticationProvider{
    
    func getToken(completion: @escaping (OtpResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        let otpResponse = OtpResponse()
        completion(otpResponse,nil)
    }
}

//Another type of auth provider
struct SsoBasedAuthProvider:AuthenticationProvider{
    
    func getToken(completion: @escaping (SsoResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        let ssoResponse = SsoResponse()
        completion(ssoResponse,nil)
    }
}

// there is some external logic to decide which type of auth provider to be used
func getProviderTypeFromSomeLogicOtherLogic() -> Int{
    return 1//simply for dummy
}
```

**Type Erasure**:

```
class _AnyCacheBox<Storage>:AuthenticationProvider{
        func getToken(completion: @escaping (Storage?, NSError?) -> Void) {
            fatalError("Never to be called")
        }
        
    }
    
    final class _CacheBox<C:AuthenticationProvider>: _AnyCacheBox<C.ResponseType>{
        private var _base:C
        
        init(base:C) {
            self._base = base
        }
        
        override func getToken(completion: @escaping (C.ResponseType?, NSError?) -> Void) {
            _base.getToken(completion: completion)
        }
    }
    
    struct AnyCache<Storage>:AuthenticationProvider{
        private let _box: _AnyCacheBox<Storage>
        
        init<C:AuthenticationProvider>(cache:C) where C.ResponseType == Storage {
            _box = _CacheBox(base: cache)
        }
        
        func getToken(completion: @escaping (Storage?, NSError?) -> Void) {
            _box.getToken(completion: completion)
        }
    }
    
    
    //Factory to return a concrete implementaton of auth provider
    class AuthProviderFactory{
        func getOTPAuthProvider() -> AnyCache<OtpResponse>{
            
            let obj : AnyCache = AnyCache(cache: OtpBasedAuthProvider())
            return obj
            
        }
        
        func getSSoAuthProvider() -> AnyCache<SsoResponse>{
            let obj : AnyCache = AnyCache(cache: SsoBasedAuthProvider())
            return obj
        }
    }
```

Below is how client can invoke methods in **Factory**-:

```
func executeNetworkCall() -> Void{
        let factory = AuthProviderFactory()
        let authProvider = factory.getOTPAuthProvider()
        authProvider.getToken{(resp,error) in
            //some code
            print(resp)
        }
    }
```

It’s a bit involving and could take time to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a type-erased provider:

```
struct AnyAuthProvider: AuthenticationProvider {
    var getToken: (@escaping (Any?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Void
    init<T: AuthenticationProvider>(provider: T) {
        self.getToken = provider.getToken
    }
    
    func getToken(completion: @escaping (Any?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        getToken(completion)
    }
}

class AuthProviderFactory{
    func getAuthProvider(type:Int) -> AnyAuthProvider {
        if(type == 1 ){
            return AnyAuthProvider(provider: SsoBasedAuthProvider())
        }
        else{
            return AnyAuthProvider(provider: OtpBasedAuthProvider())
        }
    }
}
```

usage :

```
var type = 1
// there is some external logic to decide which type of auth provider to be used
func getProviderTypeFromSomeLogicOtherLogic() -> Int{
    return type
}

func executeNetworkCall() -> Void{
    let factory = AuthProviderFactory()
    let authProvider = factory.getAuthProvider(type:getProviderTypeFromSomeLogicOtherLogic())
    authProvider.getToken{(resp,error) in // (Any?, NSError)
        //some code
        print(String(describing: resp))
    }
}

executeNetworkCall() // Optional(__lldb_expr_3.SsoResponse())
type = 2
executeNetworkCall() // Optional(__lldb_expr_3.OtpResponse())
```

Having `resp` of type `Any?` may not be practical but you did not specify what you intend to do with it. Let's say that you want to *do stuff* with your responses, you can create a protocol:

```
protocol Response {
    func doStuff()
}
struct OtpResponse: Response {
    func doStuff() {
        print("OtpResponse")
    }
}

struct SsoResponse: Response {
    func doStuff() {
        print("SsoResponse")
    }
}
```

and define `AnyAuthProvider` this way:

```
struct AnyAuthProvider: AuthenticationProvider {
    var getToken: (@escaping (Response?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Void
    init<T: AuthenticationProvider>(provider: T) where T.ResponseType: Response {
        self.getToken = provider.getToken
    }
    
    func getToken(completion: @escaping (Response?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        getToken(completion)
    }
}

func executeNetworkCall() -> Void{
    let factory = AuthProviderFactory()
    let authProvider = factory.getAuthProvider(type:getProviderTypeFromSomeLogicOtherLogic())
    authProvider.getToken{(resp,error) in
        //some code
        resp?.doStuff()
    }
}

executeNetworkCall() // prints "SsoResponse"
type = 2
executeNetworkCall() // prints "OtpResponse"
```